Permission Denied when i use .env file to store the variables ,it works if i directly use the variables without .env
Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project
whenever I try to tarnsfer all the variables to .env ,I am getting this above error message.
.env file:
VITE_API_KEY: "*****",
VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN: "*****",
VITE_PROJECT_ID: "*****",
VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET: "*****",
VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID:"*****",
VITE_APP_ID: "*****",

here is my conf.js file :
 import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

    const conf = {
      apiKey: String(import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY),
      authDomain: String(import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
      projectId: String(import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID),
      storageBucket: String(import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
      messagingSenderId: String(import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID),
      appId: String(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID),
    };

// Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(conf);
    export const db = getFirestore(app);
    export const storage = getStorage(app);
    export default app;

i have already set the rules to the below code but error still exist.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}


And that .env file is.... where? Because it needs to be in a specific location
